# Why isn't my script writing to my current directory when I use the "open" function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am brand new to Python and I am trying to wrap my head around this one but my searches have not yet revealed an answer to this problem. I am using Python 3.8.5 on Windows 10.

I have two .py files, both in `C:/Scripts/`. `test1.py` has this code:

```
f = open("C:/Scripts/test3.txt", "wt")
f.write("Hello world")
f.close()
```

And `test2.py` has this code:

```
file = open("C:/Scripts/test3.txt", "rt")
data = file.read()
print(data)
file.close()
```

I have an administrator command prompt up, and my directory is `C:/Scripts`. I type `python test1.py`, and the script executes, but the file (`test3.txt`) does not appear in the directory in Windows Explorer. But then if I type `python test2.py`, it prints `Hello world` - so this file is being written ***somewhere***, I just can't understand where!

The same thing happens if I change the absolute path to a relative one (if I type `"test3.txt"` instead of `"C:/Scripts/test3.txt"`.

I believe that Python itself is installed at `C:\Users\sharkyc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`.

Edit: Here is my output along with a directory listing:

```
C:\Scripts>python test1.py

C:\Scripts>python test2.py
Hello world

C:\Scripts>dir C:\Scripts
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is {redacted}

 Directory of C:\Scripts

08/04/2020  06:13 PM    <DIR>          .
08/04/2020  06:13 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/04/2020  05:40 PM             1,183 sftp_test.py
08/04/2020  06:13 PM                73 test1.py
08/04/2020  06:12 PM                77 test2.py
               3 File(s)          1,333 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  126,490,955,776 bytes free
```

edit: Commenters were able to help me identify where the files were going, and it looks like this was my security software (Comodo) sandboxing my Python instance. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Did you refresh explorer?

Comment: I'm on mobile now so can't test but: What happens when you add an r before the path, e.g. `r"my/path/file.txt"`.

Comment: @BramVanroy That doesn't affect forward slashes.

Comment: @superb rain: Sure: C:\Scripts>python test1.py

C:\Scripts>python test2.py
Hello world

C:\Scripts>dir C:\Scripts
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is {redacted}

 Directory of C:\Scripts

08/04/2020  06:13 PM    <DIR>          .
08/04/2020  06:13 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/04/2020  05:40 PM             1,183 sftp_test.py
08/04/2020  06:13 PM                73 test1.py
08/04/2020  06:12 PM                77 test2.py
               3 File(s)          1,333 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  126,490,955,776 bytes free

Comment: @Mad Physicist Yes, I have refreshed Explorer after running test1.py.

Comment: @Bram Vanroy That didn't seem to do anything different than before.

Comment: What happens if you change the second script to read itself instead of the text file?

Comment: Wasn't there a feature where writes to certain directories would be transparently redirected to a different directory? I remember it being introduced to deal with all the programs that wrote to their own install directory under Program Files, back when Microsoft was trying to tighten up security. Maybe what's going on is related to that.

Comment: @superb rain: If I make that change, it reads itself correctly (I tried both test2.py and C:/Scripts/test2.py).

Comment: Yeah, this sounds a lot like UAC virtualization. Your file is probably going into the UAC VirtualStore.

Comment: @superb rain: When I ran the dir, test2 was only opening "test3.txt" instead of "C:/Scripts/test3.txt" - sorry about that, I am testing a lot of things trying to find the solution here! I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you tried searching the file (with Windows Explorer or `dir test3.txt /s` from the root)?

Comment: I found it with that method! It wasn't in AppData\Local\VirtualStore, but it was in C:\VTRoot\HarddiskVolume1\Scripts. It looks like this is my Comodo security software sandboxing me. I had tried to search with Windows, but didn't get any results back for test3.txt, but the command prompt way worked (I did not know how to do that.) Thank you so much!

Comment: Interesting that it was able to read the text file from the sandbox but itself from outside the sandbox. I guess reading allows outside access and tries both inside and outside...

Comment: It's probably the case that both scripts use the same sandbox, so you have no problem reading or writing from python

Comment: Doesn't Explorer have a way to search for files? Find `test3.txt`…